# In PHP Apache setup, on memdump $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] provide me different output, sometime with www and some time without www. Why?

Tags: php, apache, logging

While verifying my website logs, It is found that the output of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], some time it is with 'www' and some time it is without 'www' with my domain name. Why this is showing me two different output of same variable.

Comment: because people sometimes request your site with 'www' and some time without 'www'?

Comment: You can follow this document for more detailed explanation and fix `Fix canonical URLs with Apache .htaccess files.` https://thesearchguru.com/fix-canonical-with-htaccess/